# Error receiving POST request in Spring with Jackson JSON conversion

Tags: json, spring, post, jackson

I'm new to both Jackson and Spring, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question. I've been working on a simple spring project which handles JSON requests. I have GET and DELETE working, but I'm getting an error when I try to POST:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/CynergyRestStarterKit] threw exception [Handler processing failed; ...with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.type(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.getJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:229)
```

Here is my Java service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<TodoItem> getTodos() {     
    return tasks;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/todo/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
TodoItem createTodo(@RequestBody TodoItem item) {
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Spring and Jackson are you using?

[This](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7063) seems to indicate a version issue.

I see that you are using 1.x of Jackson (codehaus vs fasterxml).  I would upgrade both Spring and Jackson to the latest version.

Comment: jackson-core-asl-1.5.6.jar

Comment: jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.6.jar

Comment: Are you using ant then? How about Spring version? We're currently running Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE and Jackson 2.2.0. Unless there is a compelling reason not to upgrade, I'd do that as a first step.

Comment: I'm using spring 3.2.4

Comment: Do they have binary versions of Jackson JARs available? I haven't really wrapped my head around Maven yet.

Comment: Ah, found the latest JARs

Comment: I assumed you were using ant because of listing the actual jar files. But one doesn't have to mean the other. I'd take the time to learn maven, there's no going back once you've used it.

Comment: Okay, that got rid of the error message. I'm now getting a "415" from the server for some reason, but I'll post that as a separate question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: My pleasure. For the 415 you might want to take a look at the produces and consumes feature in Spring: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-request-mapping-consumes-produces

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using spring-webmvc 3.2.9, after several retires i found that my project needed the following libraries:

- jackson-annotations-2.3.3
- jackson-core-2.3.3
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13
- jackson-core-asl-19.3

So adding these solved the problem